# Yii Debug Toolbar error: not finding javascript lib

Tags: php, javascript, yii, toolbar, xdebug

I downloaded the Debug Toolbar today (7/5/12) from github, and followed the installation instructions.

https://github.com/malyshev/yii-debug-toolbar

I'm getting the following javascript error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: yiiDebugToolbar is not defined"

...on this line:

```
(function($) {$(function(){yiiDebugToolbar.init()})}(jQuery));
```

I checked and the yii.debugtoolbar.js lib is installed under 'assets/84af4f51'. I also stepped through the php code and confirmed registerScriptFile() is being called for this file in YiiDebugToolbar.php.

Kind of stuck what's going on here. Is it a bug or is there some setup step I missed?

I'm running:

Yii 1.1.9

Comment: Are you positive that jQuery has loaded prior to calling that line of code? Please post a full example at jsfiddle.net to help us give you an answer.

Comment: @darkAsPitch: thx for your comment. I'm rather new to Yii, so as to whether jQuery has loaded, I would assume yes as this is a Yii extension and Yii should just "do the right thing". I'll see if I can confirm this though. Also I'll try to post an ex at jsfiddle but not sure how since as I mentioned this is all done via Yii's framework.

Comment: @darkAsPitch: on 2nd check, I don't think jQuery has loaded prior...as the app is a CMS alot of it is very abstracted out, I'm not even sure the debug toolbar can work with what we are doing. In any case, if you rewrite your comment as an answer I'll check it.